# Mock generic class using Mockito

Tags: mockito

I have below generic class and I m mocking its method xmlToObject() using mockito as below, however, the class is not getting mocked and call is going inside the method body. Secondly, if the call is going to method body the input parameter string is null.

```
// Mocking code:
String responseXml = "<myDetails><resultCode>000000</resultCode><resultDesc>done</resultDesc></myDetails>";

MyDetails resp = new MyDetails();
byte b1 = 0; // 1 byte.
resp.setResultCode(b1);
resp.setResultDesc("");

JAXBElement<MyDetails> queryMyDetailsJaxb=  new JAXBElement( 
                            new QName(MyDetails.class.getSimpleName()), MyDetails.class, resp);

XMLToObject<MyDetails> mockFoo = (XMLToObject<MyDetails>) mock(XMLToObject.class);
when(mockFoo.xmlToObject(responseXml ,MyDetails.class)).thenReturn(queryMyDetailsJaxb);

Actual Class:

public class XMLToObject<T> {
    public JAXBElement<T> xmlToObject(String xmlString, Class<T> t){
            System.out.println("Inside xmlToObject with xmlString: "+xmlString+", object.class: "+t);

        JAXBElement<T> resultObject = null;
        StreamSource streamSource = null;
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = null;
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = null; 
        try {  
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(t);  
            jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            streamSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
            resultObject = (JAXBElement<T>) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(streamSource, t);
            System.out.println("resultObject.class: "+resultObject.getClass());

            return resultObject;
        } catch (JAXBException e) {  
            System.out.println("xmlToObject: "+e.printStackTrace());
        }
        return resultObject;  
    }   

}


Please guide me how can i mock my class and return the custom made object while mocking.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
when(mockFoo.xmlToObject(responseXml ,MyDetails.class)).thenReturn(queryMyDetailsJaxb);
```

to

```
when(mockFoo.xmlToObject(anyString(),any(Class.class))).thenReturn(queryMyDetailsJaxb);
```

Comment: It did not work. call is going inside xmlToObject() method; hence the class is not mocked.

Comment: you must be injecting the object mockfoo to your class object that you are testing . Can you add that snippet of code as well that is the class that you are trying to test